# Ivy: Using dynamic revisions

Tags: dynamic, ivy, revision

I'm having problems understanding how I to use dynamic revisions of [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) effectively in my Java projects.

Currently, I have the following layout:

```
lib-a
revision: 1.0.0
status: release
dependencies: none

lib-b
revision: 2.0.0
status: release
dependencies: lib-a, rev 1.0.0

project-a
revision: 3.0.0
status: release
dependencies: lib-b, rev 2.0.0

project-b
revision: 4.0.0
status: release
dependencies: lib-b, rev 2.0.0
```

That means I always keep the status to `release` and use explicit version numbers.
If I would change `lib-a` during development, say `lib-a`, this is quite painful.

I save the changes in `lib-a`, update the revision in the ivy file to `1.0.1` for a minor change. Then i need to update the dependencies of lib-b to announce the revision 1.0.1 of lib-a. Now I could either update the revision of `lib-b` and also `project-a` because `project-a` is the executable and contains integration tests which I need to run.

The second way is to re-publish `lib-b` with updated dependencies but same version. This usually works with ant on command line but not for NetBeans with [ivy-beans](https://code.google.com/p/ivybeans/) plugin. They still use a cached version of the ivy file of `lib-b.` So I need to clean to local cache to make it work.

I use a common `build-ivy.xml` ant script that is in our SVN repository for all projects. Each project has a `build.xml` in the project's root that most of the time simply includes the `build-ivy.xml`. Sometimes necessary tasks are added or overwritten.
I've just read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696831/overriding-an-ivy-dependencies-revision) and [here](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/bestpractices.html) that the solution might be using dynamic revisions.
As far as I understand it, I would set the revision in all ivy files to `integration-latest` and set the status in all ivy files to `integration`. Then, ivy would always resolve the latest version automatically. 
But what would I set the revision of my modules to? Omit it completely?
How would I create a release version? Do I need to change all ivy files and set the status to `release` or would I perform a deliver task before publishing a module with overwriting the status to `release` if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest reading the following tutorial on multi-module projects in Ivy.

- http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/multiproject.html

ANT builds traditionally are big and monolithic. what you need to do is emulate Maven's way of splitting a large project up into a series of smaller builds. Each sub-build publishes it's artifact into ivy's local repo.

Ivy has lots of useful tasks for this kind of structure:

- [buildlist](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildlist.html) - Called from your overall main build file. Use to look into each sub-module's ivy.xml and determine the proper build order (Some modules depende on others)
- [buildnumber](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/buildnumber.html) - Looks at what is already published and generate the next build number in the sequence
- [publish](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/publish.html) - Push artifacts into local repo (or a foreign one, if configured in the ivysettings.xml file)

Comment: We recently implemented this for our projects. Basically the following steps where necessary:

Comment: It generally works. Basically the following steps where necessary: 1. Within the `<info>` tag, completely remove the `revision` attribute and change the `status` attribute to `"integration"`. 2. In dependent libs, change the `rev` attr within the `<dependency>` tag to `latest.integration`. 3. In the ant build file, to `<ivy:resolve>` task, add `resolveMode="dynamic"` and add some version magic as explained in the above link. This works in commandline if you change `lib-a`, pub-local, then resolving `project-a` it will find the updated `lib-a`. Unfortunately, it wont work with ivy-beans.

Comment: @ebeb Do you really need to set the resolveMode attribute on the resolve task?

Comment: Yup, I tried that first but without `resolveMode="dynamic"`, changes in `lib-a` were not recognized when resolving `project-a`. I had to re-publish `lib-b` to make `project-a` find the new dynamic revision of `lib-a`.

Comment: @jaw, @MarkO'Connor you can also add **resolveMode** to your ivy settings file:  `<module organisation="OrgName" resolveMode="dynamic"/>` see [ivy module documentation](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/settings/module.html)