# How Does Ivy Work With Version Control Tags

Tags: tags, dependencies, ivy

I am currently trying to find out how the Ivy workflow would be when generating VC tags (We're using SVN, but it doesn't matter).

The thing is, we have developed multiple libraries that depend on each other. To ease development, the dependency tag within `ivy.xml`has the attribute `rev` set to `latest.integration`.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="my-company" name="my-lib" rev="latest.integration"/>
</dependencies>
```

It was actually the result form [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083972/ivy-using-dynamic-revisions) on StackOverflow. This helps so that we can make changes quickly in one library and that run unit test in our main application without the need to manually change the revision.

Once the development is done, we publish the libs to out internal shared Ivy repository and create an SVN tag.

The problem that arises is that once we need to rebuild the software from a tag Ivy still points to `latest.integration` which, at a later point in time, will most probably point to a another integration build, maybe even to a later published version (depending on the resolver config).

Now that question is obvious: what is the best way to have Ivy to resolve to the published revisions that were `integration.latest` at the time the VCS tag was created. And it would be very helpful if the answer is not "enter published revisions by hand before you create the tag". Maybe I need to add something to my ANT build script, maybe some changes in my `settings.xml` or `ivy.xml`.

Since Ivy is quite a smart and handy little tool, I guess there must be a way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ivy [deliver task](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/deliver.html) is used to create a resolved ivy file from the project's original. By "resolved" I mean a file fit to be published into a remote repository. This means not only are the dynamic dependencies resolved, the optional revision and status attributes are set in the module's [info tag](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/info.html).

The following example creates an ivy.xml file in the build directory:

```
<ivy:deliver deliverpattern="${build.dir}/ivy.xml" pubrevision="${project.version}" status="release"/>
```

Check the file you'll discover the dependency versions are set.

At this point it is worth noting that this ability is one of subtle but important points that separates ivy from Maven. Ivy allows your automated release system to simply create tag and run the build. Take a look at the convoluted steps required by Maven and automated by it's [release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) :

1. Check that there are no uncommitted changes in the sources
2. Check that there are no SNAPSHOT dependencies
3. Change the version in the POMs from x-SNAPSHOT to a new version (you will be prompted for the versions to use)
4. Transform the SCM information in the POM to include the final destination of the tag
5. Run the project tests against the modified POMs to confirm everything is in working order
6. Commit the modified POMs
7. Tag the code in the SCM with a version name (this will be prompted for)
8. Bump the version in the POMs to a new value y-SNAPSHOT (these values will also be prompted for)
9. Commit the modified POMs

Count carefully.... That's 2 commits and a tag operation..... All because Maven's module version is mandatory and we're trying to capture in the SCM the resolved dependencies....

So, my advise is to be wary of emulating Maven. When I tag my code I capture a point in time, when I built the code. I rely on the fact that the ivy file pushed to my remote repository is fully resolved. The truly paranoid could of course keep a local copy of this ivy file, but it would never be the file that was used to build the original. In practice it's never possible to truly reproduce the original binary, just something that approximates to it.

## Additional info

To help understand how the deliver task is used, the following examples show how it's used to create resolved Maven POM files when publishing ANT artefacts into a Maven repository like Nexus:

- [Convert ivy.xml to pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426011/convert-ivy-xml-to-pom-xml/9429286#9429286)
- [Automate ivy revision increase for all my projects using ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384024/automate-ivy-revision-increase-for-all-my-projects-using-ant-script/8392205#8392205)

Comment: Thanks Mark. I think the deliver task is exactly what I want. You wrote, that you rely on published versions. But in our case, we don't publish the main executable application to the repo because it won't ever by resolved by anyone. So I don't probably need the "delivered" ivy.xml files for libs but for the main application.

Comment: However, I'm still unsure what a workflow could look like. My attemp would be to create an ANT task that creates an `ivy-delivered.xml`in the project root which will get checked in to the VC repo. Then, whenever a tagged version needs to be reproduced, the delivered xml will be used to overwrite the ivy.xml and then the application will be built. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @jaw Yes certainly makes sense. You're saving the "ivy-delivered.xml" within Subversion in order to recreate the build, should disaster strike. I take an alternative approach of using an "ivy.xml" file stored in my release repository. In my case I use Nexus as a versioned store of all my release binaries (and dependencies of those binaries). I tag my source code repository so that I can see the source that was used to create the binary. It would be a rare event for me to forced into rebuilding a release. As stated eariler it's impossble to produce *exactly* the same file.

Comment: Actually we had this "rare event" two times in the last few months which is why I'm asking ;) The reason was not to recreate the exact build but to create a bugfix branch from that tag. However, a few libs had evolved (including interface changes) over time so we needed to use the old versions of these libs to avoid possible incompatibilities.